# How to compare two SQL Server tables and insert to column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-update

I have a table called `TableA` that looks something like this:

```
GID      Type
---------------
KLMOE    mb
IENOL    mb-sd
OLEOE    od
OELCJ    mb-sd
```

and another table called `TableB` that looks like this:

```
GID      Synch
---------------
KLMOE    
IENOL    
OLEOE    
OELCJ
```

I'm just wondering how can I compare both tables using the `GID` column and check the `Type` to see whether it's `mb-sd` or not. If it is `mb-sd`, then set the `TableB` `Synch` column to `NO`. If it is another type, then set that column to `YES`.

For example, the final `TableB` output should look something like this:

```
GID      Synch
---------------
KLMOE    YES
IENOL    NO
OLEOE    YES
OELCJ    NO
```

I have this so far but it's not working yet so I would be really appreciated it if I can get any help or suggestion

```
UPDATE TableB
SET Synch = (CASE 
                 WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                              FROM TableA
                              WHERE TableA.GID = TableB.GID 
                                AND TableA.[Type] = 'mb-sd') 
                     THEN 'YES' 
                     ELSE 'NO' 
             END
```

Comment: Your query looks good, what is the problem that you have with it?

Comment: The problem looks to be that he flipped the condition of YES/NO?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `INNER JOIN` with the `UPDATE` to get your results

but your query works also https://dbfiddle.uk/D8DxRE-i

```
UPDATE t1
SET Synch = CASE 
            WHEN t2.[Type] = 'mb-sd' 
            THEN 'YES' 
            ELSE 'NO' 
        END
FROM TableB t1 INNER JOIN TableA t2 On t1.[GID] = t2.[GID]
```

```
4 rows affected
```

```
SELECt * FROM TableB
```

| GID | Synch |
| --- | --- |
| KLMOE | NO |
| IENOL | YES |
| OLEOE | NO |
| OELCJ | YES |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/I8T5coHd)

Comment: Using the alias `UPDATE t1` would be wise, otherwise an unexpected cross-join could occur.